# Concurrent normals conjecture

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

It is conjectured that if $K$ is a convex body in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, then there exists a point in the interior of $K$ which is the point of concurrency of normals from $2n$ points on the boundary of $K$. This has been proved for $n=2$ and $3$ by E. Heil. For $n=4$, a proof appeared (under a smoothness assumption on the boundary) in

*Pardon, John*, [**Concurrent normals to convex bodies and spaces of Morse functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00208-010-0629-9), Math. Ann. 352, No. 1, 55-71 (2012). [ZBL1242.52006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1242.52006).

but a reviewer’s remark in zbMATH says that in this paper, the proof of the first theorem "does not seem to be quite correct". So my question is:

What is the current status of this conjecture for $n=4$?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let me address the specific complaint of that review.  The situation is the following.  Our (bounded, open) convex set is denoted $K\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ with closure $\overline K$, and we consider the "distance to $p$" function $d_p:\partial K\to\mathbb R$ for $p\in\overline K$.  Let $V\subseteq\overline K$ be the set of $p\in\overline K$ for which $d_p$ has exactly one local minimum.  I claimed in my paper that "it is clear that $V$ is closed".  As the reviewer correctly points out, this is false (counterexample: $K$ the unit ball).  But here is a corrected version: "if $d_p$ has finitely many local minima for every $p\in\overline K$, then $V$ is closed".  Indeed, if $d_p$ has **finitely many** local minima, then if we perturb $p$ the number of local minima can only increase.  This corrected version of the statement is sufficient for the proof given in the paper, since if $d_p$ has infinitely many local minima for some $p$, this exactly means that there are infinitely many normals to $\partial K$ which are concurrent at $p$.  So the reviewer's remark doesn't invalidate the argument.

I have to admit, this is not a well written paper, and I would be surprised if it did not contain a number of other equally badly presented arguments.  I can say that I reread it a couple of years ago and was more or less convinced by the proof.  However, I have not discussed it in detail with anyone.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanations. In the paper, you wrote that any Morse function in the 3-sphere with at least 3 local maxima and 2 local minima has at least 8 critical points. Is it a trivial remark? Or is it a consequence of the below theorem by Camacho and Scardua ? A Morse foliation F (of a compact connected manifold M) such that the number c of centers and the number s of saddles in Sing(F) satisfy c>s, then c=s+2 and M is homeomorphic to an dim(M)-sphere or c=s+1 and M is a Eells-Kuiper manifold.

Comment: It follows immediately from the "Morse inequalities", but I prefer to think about it more concretely as follows.  I claim that any Morse function $f:S^3\to\mathbb R$ with $k$ local minima must have at least $k-1$ index one critical points (this implies what we want since $3+2+2+1=8$).  This is obvious if one thinks about how the topology of the sublevel sets changes when passing through a Morse critical point: every time we pass a local minimum the number of components increases, and the only way for the number of components to decrease is if we pass through an index one critical point.

Comment: Dear John, I am trying to understand your proof but I have difficulties.(may be from my inexperience of the subject). In your proof of Lemma 4.2, you wrote "...which has nonzero H2". But, it seems to me that H2 has not been defined before in the text (the one dated "17 December 2008")... Can you help me ?

Comment: @Clement $H_2$ is second homology

Comment: Dear John. In the proof of Lemma 3.3, you wrote "Then E is a bundle
over B with fiber D²".  Is it for the special case n=3 or is it true for any n ?

Comment: @Clement: Indeed, the fiber is $D^{n-1}$ not $D^2$ like I wrote.  (Also note that, contrary to standard usage, it seems like I'm using $D^k$ to denote the open, rather than the closed, $k$-disk.  Probably it would be clearer to write $\mathbb R^k$ instead.)

Comment: Dear John, I am a bit confused: did you assume in the lemma that the closure of K is the union of A and B?

Comment: Dear Clement, yes, that is correct, it should be assumed that the union of A and B is the closure of K (and thank you for taking the time to read this paper despite the confusing omissions).

Comment: Dear John, I have other remarks on your paper. Page 59, you wrote; ."If H turns out to be empty, then the proof becomes much easier. We can skip to Remark 1 below, from which point the proof is in the same vein as the proof of Theorem 1. If H is empty, then the list of properties in Remark 1 all hold if one replaces
the subscript 1’s with subscript 0’s ...". But it seems to me that in this case,r_0 and R_0 are not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Dear Clement, could you elaborate a bit more?  The functions r_0 and R_0 here in case n=4 are the same as in the case n=3, so do you have the same concern about the proof for n=3?

Comment: Dear John, in the case n=3, if you have at least two minima and two maxima then you are done; so you may assume in your proof that the condition "the closure of K is the union of A and B" (which you omitted in the statement) is fulfilled. But, for n=4, it is not the case.

Comment: @Clement, Indeed, this is the entire point of the proof for the case n=4.  We can start with A and B being the loci where there is a unique local max/min, respectively.  As you note, these might not cover all of K when n=4.  The whole point of the proof is to carefully analyze what happens when there are exactly two local max's and exactly two local min's and show that the functions r and R can be extended to two larger sets which do cover all of K (closure).  See the top of page 68 where Lemma 3 is applied and it is noted explicitly that the hypothesis that A and B cover Kbar is satisfied.